# Understanding scope with non-standard evaluations in R data.table

Tags: r, scope, data.table, non-standard-evaluation

How can I ensure that my nonstandard evaluation<sup>1</sup> using `data.table` is inheriting the variables it needs from the parent frame?

Based on my understanding of dynamic scope, my code below should work, but it doesn't.  What am I doing wrong?

#### Details

I have a list of many functions I want to apply to a single `data.table` that return boolean checks and messages (for when the check is TRUE).  For example, let's say I am auditing a table of accounts.

```
library(data.table)
#----- Example data -----------------------------------------------------------
n <- 100
set.seed(123)
df <- data.table( acct_id      = paste0('ID',seq(n)),
                  acct_balance = round(pmax(rnorm(n,1000,5000),0)),
                  days_overdue = round(pmax(rnorm(n,20,20),0))
                  )
#----- Example list of rules to check (real case has more elements)------------
AuditRules <- list(
  list(
    msg_id = 1,
    msg_cat = 'Balance',
    cond_fn = function(d) d[, acct_balance > balance_limit ],
    msg_txt = 
      function(d) d[, paste('Account',acct_id,'balance is',
                            acct_balance - balance_limit, 
                            'over the limit.')]
  ),
  list(
    msg_id = 2,
    msg_cat = 'Overdue',
    cond_fn = function(d) d[, days_overdue > grace_period ],
    msg_txt = 
      function(d) d[, paste('Account',acct_id,'is overdue',
                            days_overdue-grace_period,
                            'days beyond grace period.')]
  )
)
```

I am looping through the list of rules and checking the dataset on each.

#### Desired Output

This works fine in the global environment.

```
balance_limit <- 1e4
grace_period  <-  14
audit <- rbindlist(
              lapply(AuditRules, function(item){
                with( item,
                      df[ cond_fn(df),
                         .(msg_id, 
                           msg_cat,
                           msg_txt = msg_txt(.SD) )
                         ]
                      )
                } )
            )
print(head(audit), row.names=FALSE)
#-----------------   Result   --------------------------------------
# msg_id msg_cat                                             msg_txt
#      1 Balance        Account ID44 balance is 1845 over the limit.
#      1 Balance        Account ID70 balance is 1250 over the limit.
#      1 Balance        Account ID97 balance is 1937 over the limit.
#      2 Overdue Account ID2 is overdue 11 days beyond grace period.
#      2 Overdue  Account ID3 is overdue 1 days beyond grace period.
#      2 Overdue  Account ID6 is overdue 5 days beyond grace period.
```

#### What doesn't work (and needs a solution)

```
rm(balance_limit, grace_period) # see "aside"

auditTheData <- function(d, balance_limit = 1e4, grace_period=14){
  rbindlist(
    lapply(AuditRules, function(item){
        with( item,
              d[ cond_fn(d),
                  .(msg_id, 
                    msg_cat,
                    msg_txt = msg_txt(.SD) )
                  ]
        )
    } )
  )
}
auditTheData(df)
```

results in the error:

> ```
> Error in eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : 
>   object 'balance_limit' not found
> ```

It's not a problem with `with()`, although I've read (`?with`) that typically one should refrain from using it for programming.  This also doesn't work:

```
auditTheData2 <- function(d, balance_limit = 1e4, grace_period=14){
  rbindlist(
    lapply(AuditRules, function(item){
          d[ item[['cond_fn']](d),
             .(msg_id, 
               msg_cat,
               msg_txt = item[['msg_txt']](.SD) )
             ]
    } )
  )
}
auditTheData2(df) # Same error
```

**Aside:** if you don't do `rm(balance_limit, grace_period)` before the "what doesn't work" function -- i.e. leave them in the global environment -- you get the desired results.  So it seems like the `function(item)` that is getting `lapply`-ed can "see" into the global environment but not the parent environment (`AuditTheData`).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>I'm using "non-standard" in the unscientific sense of "unusual" here. Idk what counts as non-standard, but that's another (and a too broad?) question.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
ar <- list(
  list(
    cat = 'Balance',
    cond_expr = quote(acct_balance > balance_limit),
    msg_expr = quote(sprintf('Account %s balance is %s over the limit.',
      acct_id, 
      acct_balance - balance_limit))
  ),
  list(
    cat = 'Overdue',
    cond_expr = quote(days_overdue > grace_period),
    msg_expr = quote(sprintf('Account %s is overdue %s days beyond grace period.', 
      acct_id, 
      days_overdue-grace_period))
  )
)

audDT = rbindlist(rapply(ar, list, "call", how = "replace"), id="msg_id")

auditem = function(d, a, balance_limit = 1e4, grace_period = 14){
    a[, {
        cond    = cond_expr[[1]]
        msg     = msg_expr[[1]]
        .(txt = d[eval(cond), eval(msg)])
    }, by=.(msg_id, cat)]
}
```

For example ...

```
> head(auditem(df, audDT))
   msg_id     cat                                                 txt
1:      1 Balance        Account ID44 balance is 1845 over the limit.
2:      1 Balance        Account ID70 balance is 1250 over the limit.
3:      1 Balance        Account ID97 balance is 1937 over the limit.
4:      2 Overdue Account ID2 is overdue 11 days beyond grace period.
5:      2 Overdue  Account ID3 is overdue 1 days beyond grace period.
6:      2 Overdue  Account ID6 is overdue 5 days beyond grace period.
```

I'm not sure which of these changes made the difference:

- `eval` predefined expressions instead of composing them in `j` inside a function
- use a table for rules, with a few benefits:

  - since every entry should have the same structure, you can verify that each is well-formed (has no missing components)
  - `msg_id` can be auto-numbered with `rbindlist` and so doesn't have to be manually typed
  - `by=` can be used instead of `lapply`, since the latter has some weird evaluation behavior

I also switched `paste` to `sprintf` but am sure that doesn't matter.

The `rapply` is necessary since data.table doesn't support calls/expressions as a column type (apparently), but does support list columns.

Comment: `rapply` is a new one on me.  Took me a while to make this work.  It turns out my sub-lists were ordered inconsistently (albeit named consistently) which quite unexpectedly (1) caused an error and (2) produced an error message about `bmerge` that was rather misleading.  Thanks again, Frank.